# Can I get a list of available locale translations from my Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, internationalization

Is there a way to retrieve from within my Google Chrome extension the list of all available translations?

For instance, my app may contain the following folders:

```
_locales\en\messages.json
_locales\fr\messages.json
_locales\es\messages.json
```

Is there a way to know that it's `en`, `fr`, and `es` from within the extension itself?

And a second question, is there any way to parse a specific `messages.json` file as the JSON data? I mean a little bit more capabilities than what's provided by `chrome.i18n.getMessage()`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes to both questions, thanks to the ability to read the extension's own folder:

> [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry)
>
> Returns a `DirectoryEntry` for the package directory.

For example, you can list locales in this way (not resilient, add your own error checks):

```
function getLocales(callback) {
  chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {
    root.getDirectory("_locales", {create: false}, function(localesdir) {
      var reader = localesdir.createReader();
      // Assumes that there are fewer than 100 locales; otherwise see DirectoryReader docs
      reader.readEntries(function(results) {
        callback(results.map(function(de){return de.name;}).sort());
      });
    });
  });
}

getLocales(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

Likewise, you can use this to obtain a FileEntry for the messages.json file and parse it.
Edit: or you can use XHR as described in [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26277026/934239) once you know the folder name.

Comment: Thanks. Speaking of error checks, I can't seem to find any good documentation on it. Say for `root.getDirectory()` what parameters is `errorCallback` (or last parameter that you skipped) called with in case of an error?

Comment: To answer my own question, `errorCallback`, or the last parameter for `root.getDirectory()`, has two handy properties `message` and `name` that have some info about the error.

Comment: Also just an update, I can't mark this as an answer, since @Xan's code example is incomplete. If someone is interested, here's a working example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryReader#example

Answer (score 1):

To know what is the current locale used by the user, you can do this:

```
currentLocale = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@ui_locale");
```

Now `currentLocale` will be something like `"en"` or `"fr"` or wathever is the locale used by the user. So now you can use it to build locale-specific URLs.

To use your `messages.json` as a Javascript Object you can:

1. Get the current locale
2. Request the `messages.json` file with an `XMLHttpRequest`
3. Parse the content into an object using the `JSON.parse()` method.

Let's say you've got a `messages.json` file like this:

```
{
    "hello": {
         "message": "Hello world!",
         "description": "Sample text used for testing."
    }
}
```

You will now do an XHR to get the file, something like this:

```
var currentLocale = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@ui_locale"),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    messages;

xhr.open("GET", "/_locales/"+currentLocale+"messages.json", false);
xhr.send();

messages = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

// now you can access the messages like this:
alert(messages["hello"].message);
```

And you'll see your message alert.