# HTML 5 & Javascript desktop application and acces to project files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm preparing small application written in HTML and JavaScript for Desktop PCs, but have huge problem to get files list from my application directory (exacly list of jpegs from gallery folder) to not hardcode all the names inside html/javascript.

Currently I'm testing app in chrome kiosk mode. And there is no server or online access. Tis application will work offline on dedicated pc machine.

What is the easiest solution to get acccess to read files from application directory?

Do I have to package my app in something like Chrome App, AppJS, Awesominum to solve this problem?

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: @BobBrown I wonder where you got that vibe, and in any case that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overlooked a [native solution in Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry):

> `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function callback)`
>
> Returns a `DirectoryEntry` for the package directory.

From that `DirectoryEntry` to the root of your app's folder you can obtain the file list required.

See [the `DirectoryEntry` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry), [HTML5Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273405/can-i-get-a-list-of-available-locale-translations-from-my-chrome-extension/26276924#26276924) for information on what to do with the obtained object. *Disregard the warnings about abandoned standards: Chrome intends to continue support for this API.*