# How do I check for existence of a resource from within the same Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Say I have the following files in my *unpacked* Google Chrome extension:

- manifest.json
- my.extension.js
- image.png

How do I check if `image.png` exists using Javascript in `my.extension.js`?

Edit:

I know *(and I think it would work)* that we could create an `<img>` element and use the `onerror` event OR use `XMLHttpRequest` to check for the existence but I am looking for a better(?) alternative solution, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Declare `my.extension.js` as [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) or [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). <sub>*([Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) will not work with the following method since the [chrome.* API provided in content scripts is limited](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts))*</sub>
2. Use [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry), as suggested by [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27207311/278405),  which is based on [HTML 5 Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry) to access the resource files and thus you can check for the file existence therein.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["my.extension.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Check Resource Existence",
  "version": "1.0",
}
```

**my.extension.js**:

```
filename = "image.png";

chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(storageRootEntry) {
  fileExists(storageRootEntry, filename, function(isExist) {
    if(isExist) {
      /* your code here */
    }
  });
});

function fileExists(storageRootEntry, fileName, callback) {
  storageRootEntry.getFile(fileName, {
    create: false
  }, function() {
    callback(true);
  }, function() {
    callback(false);
  });
}
```

Comment: Remark: a content script will work if the file is declared in `web_accessible_resources`, but then ANY origin can check for existence of that file (and consequently detect if your extension is installed)

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry):

> `chome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function callback)`
>
> Returns a DirectoryEntry for the package directory.

You'll then be able to list files in your extension. For an example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26276924/934239).

That said, your XHR approach should also work. You just need to catch that error.