# Javascript, FileReader vs XMLHttpRequest for reading a local file?

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, filereader

I'm trying to read a local file with javascript and a Google Chrome App (it may not be possible through Chrome I think), but I can't see what's the latest approach to the problem.

I can read it with the following code:

```
obj.read = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var file_path = 'file_name.xml';
        xmlhttp.open('GET', file_path, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                let xml = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
                console.log(xml);
                console.log(xmlDoc);
                resolve(xmlDoc);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

But it is like I should be using something like

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
    };
})(file_path);

var file_path = 'file_name.xml';
var file_parts = [
    new Blob(['you construct a file...'],{type: 'text/plain'}), 
    'Same way as you do with blob',
    new Uint16Array([33])
];
var file = new File(file_parts, file_path);
reader.readAsText(file);
```

(copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24495213/826815)
(I'm having a hard time finding literature on this topic)

So, what's the way to do it?

Comment: A few things are not clear: 1) "I can read it with the following code" - so why is that not a good approach? Why are you trying to change it? 2) What exactly do you mean by a "local file"? Your examples are for a file inside your app's package. Is that all you need?

Comment: 1) that's the question, it is "the" good approach? is there any "second" approach? if so, which one should I choose? 2) by local file I mean a file located in the same folder where the App is located, but since I haven't yet packaged it, I can only guess it will be in the app's package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach (`XMLHttpRequest` for a file in the package) is perfectly valid and likely to be easier if all you need is the whole file.

---

What you call a "second approach" is lifted from a question about *instantiating a `File` object*, not reading an actual file. This would not allow you to read an existing file, just create a "virtual" file that can be used in DOM forms.

There's the whole [HTML `FileSystem` API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), which is not implemented anywhere but Chrome and as such documentation is scarce and fraught with big scary red warnings. You *can* actually use it for the purpose you state - reading App's own files - by starting with [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry), but that's probably overkill in your particular case and again, you'll have a hard time finding examples of doing so.

I can think of only two reasons to disturb the slumber of the beast that is `FileSystem` API for App's own files:

1. You don't know, at runtime, what files are included. Then you can [use it to list files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26276924/934239). Rare, but possible.
2. You need a more fine-grained access than "get me the whole thing", for example you only need a chunk of a large file.

Note that `FileSystem` API is primarily used in Chrome for `chrome.fileSystem` Apps API. Considering that Chrome is going to support Chrome Apps on Chrome OS for a while, it's likely to stay, despite being non-standard.

Surviving documentation:

- The above-mentioned HTML5Rocks article: [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)
- Last public standards document: [File API: Directories and System](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/)
- Actual standards document on `File` API (that your "second example" is covered by): [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/)

Comment: is **xmlhttprequest** best approach for reading whole _.txt. files or **FileReader()**